# Querying two collections at same time with Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections

If I have 2 collections of objects, is it possible to effectively join them, and select from both of them, in one query?

For example:

```
var collection1 = GetSomeData();
var collection2 = GetSomeMoreData();

var myResult = from x in collection1
               from y in collection2
               where x.SomeProperty = "Yes"
               where y.SomeProperty = "Yes"
               select x, select y;
```

`GetSomeData`, and `GetSomeMoreData` both return `IEnumerable<MyType>`

Obviously this doesn't compile... but hopefully it gives an illustration of what I'm trying to do the idea...

Comment: What exactly should `myResult` contain? Maybe add an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you want [`Enumerable.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894.aspx):

```
var myResult = collection1.Concat(collection2)
                          .Where(x => x.SomeProperty == "Yes");
```

or in query-syntax:

```
var myResult = from x in collection1.Concat(collection2)
               where x.SomeProperty == "Yes"
               select x;
```

Note that the word 'join' you use, in the context of LINQ, normally refers to finding (and pairing / grouping up) common elements between two sequences based on some key. That's not what you intend to do, is it?

Comment: Thanks... I should of thought about string.concat ;-) Terminology of "join" was sending me round in circles